# Tableau Include Latest Revision (Publish) Date in Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard I am developing in 2018.2.3 Desktop that will eventually get published to our internal Tableau Web Portal. I am writing a "Help" tab that has some documentation, directions, etc. for users to view in case they are curious what report is for, how to use it, definitions, etc..

One piece that I want to include at the header of this are three dates:

- Report Created
- Report Data Refresh
- Report Publish Date

The first two are simple, the "Report Created" is just text, since I have no idea how to get the date the report was actually started. Text is fine for this. The Data Refresh is simple as using the, "". That works perfectly.

My only issue is I'd like to include the most recent publish date / revision. Now, I see this in the Tableau Web as meta data on the dashboard, but I'd like it to be part of this "Help" page. Is there a way to do this with some sort of dimension or variable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Server and not Online, you can take a look at getting this data from the `WORKGROUP` database that Tableau Server runs from. Use this guide from [Tableau](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_server_repo.htm) to get that setup.

Then you will want to look at the `workbook`, `sites` and `workbook_versions` tables. Here is a sample query that could help.

```
select s.name site, w.name workbook, wv.version_number, wv.published_at, w.updated_at 
from workbooks w 
left join sites s on w.site_id = s.id
left join workbook_versions wv on w.id = wv.workbook_id
where upper(w.name) like '%<WORKBOOK>%'
group by 1,2,3,4,5
having w.updated_at = max(w.updated_at)
```

`published_at` is a timestamp of the initial publish.

`updated_at` is the last date it was updated.

`version_number` is a count of how many times the workbook has been published to on that site.

Here is a [data dictionary](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/data_dictionary.htm) for all the other available tables.

You can pull this query as a new data source and build the text that you want to display.

Comment: Awesome! Quick question, my current data source is a database table from a reporting database, pulling this this into my Data Sources, do I just do a "Full Join" on that so it includes everything from both queries? Sorry, still new to Tableau. Thanks!

Comment: I would keep this as a separate data source. Select `Data/New Data Source`. You can then just use it on the one tab where you want to provide the information. This way you wont introduce any join or blend issues that could slow your workbook down.